# Unable to download large base64 files in Google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-audio-api

I am trying to download base64 encoded files but they get stuck. The chrome icon shows an indicator of the file being downloaded but there is nothing in the downloads section.

My use case is: Converting audio(a wav file) to base64, make some manipulations and download it back on the client side.

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried at the Question to reproduce the issue? Why do you convert the file to a `data URI`? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.